# Redirect Authenticated user to home page for invalid url hit

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I have a simple jhipster app. I'd like the authenticated users to get redirect to home page for invalid `url`. Previously I had changed `home.state.js` and added `login.state.js` as mentioned below:

**home.state.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('anvilIqApp')
        .config(stateConfig);

    stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            parent: 'app',
            url: '/home',
            data: {
                authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
            },
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                mainTranslatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate,$translatePartialLoader) {
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('home');
                    return $translate.refresh();
                }]
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

**login.state.js**

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('anvilIqApp')
        .config(stateConfig);

    stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('login', {
            parent: 'app',
            url: '/',
            data: {
                authorities: []
            },
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html',
                    controller: 'LoginController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                mainTranslatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate,$translatePartialLoader) {
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('login');
                    return $translate.refresh();
                }]
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

As you can see, the root is now login page. When an authenticated user hits an invalid `url`, the login page as usual appears. I want to redirect the user to `/home` for invalid url hit.

inside **auth.service.js** I've got this snippet:

```
function authThen () {
    var isAuthenticated = Principal.isAuthenticated();

    // an authenticated user can't access to login and register pages
    if (isAuthenticated && $rootScope.toState.parent === 'account' && ($rootScope.toState.name === 'login' || $rootScope.toState.name === 'register')) {
        $state.go('home');
    }

    // recover and clear previousState after external login redirect (e.g. oauth2)
    if (isAuthenticated && !$rootScope.fromState.name && getPreviousState()) {
        var previousState = getPreviousState();
        resetPreviousState();
        $state.go(previousState.name, previousState.params);
    }

    if ($rootScope.toState.data.authorities && $rootScope.toState.data.authorities.length > 0 && !Principal.hasAnyAuthority($rootScope.toState.data.authorities)) {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            // user is signed in but not authorized for desired state
            $state.go('accessdenied');
        }
        else {
            // user is not authenticated. stow the state they wanted before you
            // send them to the login service, so you can return them when you're done
            storePreviousState($rootScope.toState.name, $rootScope.toStateParams);

            // now, send them to the signin state so they can log in
            $state.go('accessdenied').then(function() {
                $state.go('login');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the otherwise option available in $urlRouterProvider. Inject $urlRouterProvider and pass the default state in that.

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

So for URL's other than the defined one's will redirect to the URL passed in otherwise.

For more details: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider